# Notification email count instead of content

Tags: notifications, outlook

Subsequent email notifications state the number of unread emails instead of the content of each subsequent email.

I use Outlook for email. The first email will state who it is from and some content. After that, I get 2 unread messages and then 3 unread messages as the notification.

Any way to change this to the actual content of the message so I know which ones to ignore and which to pay attention to?